# XAMLParseException occurred

Tags: c#, xaml

In my XAML code, I got a weird error that I cant figure out how to fix. I got a error stating:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Initialization of 'Verton_For_Windows_Desktop.MainWindow' threw an exception.' Line number '66' and line position '7'.

Here's my code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Verton_For_Windows_Desktop.MainWindow"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Verton Ai" Height="573.523" Width="358.453" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{x:Null}" GlowBrush="#FF1768FF" WindowTitleBrush="#FF2470FF" TitleForeground="White" Foreground="#FF2470FF" Topmost="True" ShowMaxRestoreButton="False" SaveWindowPosition="True" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" SizeToContent="Height">
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="openButton">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="44"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="12"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-2"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-2"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
<Controls:MetroWindow.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter" SourceName="button"/>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource openButton}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Triggers>
<Grid Background="#FF1768FF">
    <Button x:Name="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,455,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Height="81" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="{x:Null}" FontSize="200" FontStyle="Italic" Cursor="Hand" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.119,0.431">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Blake Weissman\OneDrive\Extra Curricular Stuff\Verton\Verton New\WindowsIcons-master\WindowsPhone\dark\appbar.microphone.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="10,402,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Type Your Command Here, Or Click The Microphone Button To Say Your Command" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="332" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF1768FF" Uid="commandText" IsKeyboardFocusedChanged="TextBox_IsKeyboardFocusedChanged"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="374" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="332" Foreground="#FF1768FF" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="20"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,480,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Height="66" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="{x:Null}" FontSize="200" FontStyle="Italic" Cursor="Hand" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.119,0.431">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Blake Weissman\OneDrive\Extra Curricular Stuff\Verton\Verton New\WindowsIcons-master\WindowsPhone\dark\appbar.settings.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,480,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Height="66" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="{x:Null}" FontSize="200" FontStyle="Italic" Cursor="Hand" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.119,0.431">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Blake Weissman\OneDrive\Extra Curricular Stuff\Verton\Verton New\WindowsIcons-master\WindowsPhone\dark\appbar.settings.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line number and position is telling you where the problem is. Last line of your file - missing a closing tag for Controls:MetroWindow

Comment: Thanks for the response, I actually forgot to copy and paste that last line of the code, opps. However, I was able to figure it out my own. Again, thanks for the response.